# Outlook desktop alert "Always on the Top"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using VMware on full screen to control a virtual computer most of the time. When I get a message in outlook on the VM, the desktop alert hides below the VMware window and I'm missing a lot of messages because of this. Is there any way to setup the desktop alert to show on the main desktop above VMware window?